# Android Library Similar to Ramotion Paper Switch

Tags: android, animation

Update :-Able to achieve  it used https://github.com/ozodrukh/CircularReveal & custom changes.

Is there any similar library like [Ramotion/Paper-Switch](https://github.com/Ramotion/paper-switch).

How can i animate the parent color change as shown in the library pic below

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CircularReveal animation as described here:

https://developer.android.com/training/material/animations.html

Just create an invisible layout with the color as a background, and show/hide it as described in the article. You'll need to calculate the center from the position of the switch, and radius based on the view size.